# ServiceLoader is returning empty list for services on Wildfly-17.0.1

Tags: java, wildfly, serviceloader, wildfly-17

```
ServiceLoader<ConnectionLoader> serviceLoader = ServiceLoader.load(ConnectionLoader.class);
```

My web application has 3 implementations of the `ConnectionLoader` service and the above API works perfectly fine on almost all the web application servers except Wildfly-17.0.1.

Wildfly-17.0.1 deployment is failing with the above API returning an empty list. And i am not able to understand why this is happening.

**My system configuration is:**

- Operating System : RHEL7.6
- MSSQL Server 2019 - 192.168.25.105
- JDK - Oracle JDK 11

**Also, I have verified that** -

- Service entries are present and correct inside the META-INF/services
- I can load the class/implementation service using reflection. So it does not seems to be a ClassLoader issue.
- But when I call the `ServiceLoader.load(ConnectionLoader.class,ConnectionLoader.class.getClassLoader())` it works perfectly fine.  Even though this works I cannot change the implementation for around 100s of services. And leave the 3rd party dependencies or code blocks in third-party jars.
- This same combination used to work last year (with JDK 1.8) and we have no idea about what's changed and why this issue is specific to this combination.

Comment: Where are your services located? Are they in your WAR or were they installed as a module? Also where is the `ServiceLoader` invoked from?

Comment: Services are located inside 
- war/web-inf/lib/jar-file1.jar
- war/web-inf/lib/jar-file2.jar
- war/web-inf/lib/jar-file3.jar

ServiceLoader is invoked from main application startup thread.

Comment: By "main application startup thread" do you mean something like a `@Startup` EJB? I just gave it a test and it seemed to work for me.